# Add left and right arrows diagonal in table

Tags: tables, arrows

I have this table:

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % aumenta espaço entre linhas
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{18 pt}  % aumenta espaço entre colunas
\begin{tabular}{ c | c c | c }
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Y}\\
%\cline{2 - 4} % linha horizontal entre as colunas
% 2 e 4
X & 0 & 1 & Total \\
\hline
0 & $P_{00}$  & $P_{01}$ & $P_{0.}$ \\
1 & $P_{10}$ & $P_{11}$ & $P_{1.}$ \\
\hline
Total & $P_{.0}$ & $P_{.1}$ & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]

I would like to draw left and right arrows in diagonal like the example picture (left and right arrows in diagonal P_00 to P_11 and P_10 to P_01)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `tikzmark` library of `tikz`package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner xsep=3pt}}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{18pt}
\begin{array}{ c | c c | c }
\hline
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Y}\\
X   & 0                             & 1                             & \mathrm{Total}    \\
\hline
0   & \tikzmarknode[is]{a}{P_{00}}  & \tikzmarknode[is]{b}{P_{01}}  & P_{0.} \\
1   & \tikzmarknode[is]{c}{P_{10}}  & \tikzmarknode[is]{d}{P_{11}}  & P_{1.} \\
\hline
\mathrm{Total}
    & P_{.0}                    & P_{.1}                      & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
    \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \draw[<->]   (a) -- (d);
  \draw[<->]   (c) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

After at least two compilation you will get:

[image]

For shorten code in table body I use `array` instead of `tabularray` and insert it in math environment.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Zarko

Comment: @flavio2f, you are welcome! When you will sufficient reputation (15 or more) you can upvote answer, however you can already accept it (after while if you will not received answer which you will more liked).